# Changing preset colors in Keynote

Tags: keynote, color

I know how to create custom color palettes in MacOS Keynote. I also know that different presentation templates come with different set of preset colors. However, I can't find a way to change this set of preset colors in a customly created template. Whenever changing colors, instead of clicking on the preset colors button and selecting the color (2 clicks, marked A on the diagram below), I need to click the color wheel, select the palette and select the color (3 clicks, marked B on the diagram below).

[image: two options to pick colors]

Is there a way to attach a palette to a template so that it becomes its custom set of preset colors?

[image: different sets of colors]

Answer (score 5):

This drove me nuts forever! It's actually pretty easy (but a little tedious). Just like you can drag a selected color from the picker to create a default (opened with the picker wheel) color OR create a new palette – once you've selected your color it will appear in the presets as the "current fill". Then, just drag the "current fill" color box onto the default palette color you want to modify. 
[image]
Here I've already dragged my grayscale and just added light indigo from dragging the current fill box to the color fill box.

Comment: It's not efficient, I have so much color in my palette

Answer (score 1):

There is an app that quickly converts your colors from Adobe ASE files into an Apple custom color palette. It is called the Color Palette Converter and you can get it on the Apple Store for $4.99. If you are an Adobe user you just make sure all the colors you want to use are in the Swatches panel of Illustrator, Photoshop, InDesign, and then choose Export to ASE from the Swatches panel menu. Open the Color Palette Converter app and drag your exported ASE file in, names and colors are all added to a palette that you can locate in the Color Palettes section of the Color panel in Keynote. Saves so much time.